# Uppercase or lowercase for global variables?

Tags: visual-studio-code, lua

I declared a global variable in lua in VS code starting with a lowercase character.

```
score = 0
```

Then I encountered an issue that a global variable should not begin with a lowercase character although it did not result in any sort of error. The code worked perfectly fine but I was constantly displayed this issue for each global variable that I declared in lowercase initial.

[image: the issue that was displayed]

This lead to a few question: "Should I begin my global variables with an uppercase letter? Will it make my code more easy to inspect and understand? Is this issue only for Lua or other languages too?". I would like to know your opinions and suggestions. Thanks y'all for the help in advance.

Comment: It's a warning from your IDE, not lua. In general, it doesn't matter how you choose variable naming as long as it is consistent across the entire code. Making it upper case helps you differentiating between local and global. You should prefer local. You can disable the warning in your IDE.

Comment: Should I use ```Score``` or ```SCORE``` for this global? Any suggestions?

Comment: all upper case are usually constants, so I personally would recommend `Score`

Comment: I also found this: http://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaStyleGuide, you can see how vague they are too

Answer (score 0):

The [Lua language server extension](https://github.com/LuaLS/lua-language-server/wiki) provides [diagnostics](https://github.com/LuaLS/lua-language-server/wiki/Diagnostics) which can be individually disabled via Visual Code Manage Settings (Ctrl+,):

1. Lua.diagnostics.disable
2. Select a diagnostic to disable. In this case [lowercase-global](https://github.com/LuaLS/lua-language-server/wiki/Diagnostics#lowercase-global)

or globally:

1. Lua.diagnostics.enable

Answer (score 0):

This style enforcement may help you catch unintentional global variables easier.

It's easy to accidentally make variables global in lua. For example if you first use the variable inside a function declaration then the variable is global. In some other languages the variable would be local. To make it less error prone it might be useful to start global variables with uppercase characters. Then the debugger will know if it was meant to be local or global and show errors if you break the styling rule, making you more aware of the global vs local scope.